# AddEventListener for button dynamically

Tags: javascript, button

Code:1 gives me error `Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null`, because button is templated after script code is executed.

**Code:1**

```
<html>
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById("buttonid");
         button.addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("alert");});
</script>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="buttonid" value="click">
</body>
</html>
```

**Code:2**

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" id="buttonid" value="click">
</body>
     <script>
        var button = document.getElementById("buttonid");
             button.addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("alert");});
     </script>
</html>
```

Here code:2 is working. I want Code:1 to be work as Code:2. How to solve this problem.

**Note:**

I don't want to use `jQuery`

Comment: just to prevent duplication, @UweB is right. in Code 1 the fire order isn't correct. script is trying to grab un-existed element. in Code 2 it works due to the same reason, just the opposite result :)

Answer (score 2):

Either:

1. Put the code that binds the event listener in a function, then bind that function as a `load` event listener on the `window` *or*
2. Bind the listener to another object (such as the `document`), capture the event object (the first argument), then check the value of `evt.target` inside the function.

Comment: 2 is most preferred way

Comment: Not necessarily, it requires firing the event handler for every click on the page. If you have a lot of them, you end up doing a lot of processing for every click.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call `.getElementById` in code 2, the page's body content is not loaded yet and then your button doesn't exist. Try using an onload event:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" id="buttonid" value="click">
</body>
     <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var button = document.getElementById("buttonid");
                 button.addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("alert");});
        });
     </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the HTML page is parsed "as is", meaning top-down, so the script executes before the button's HTML code has been processed by the browser. Thus, your call to `getElementById` will return `null`.

If you really insist on having your JavaScript at the top of the page, you will need attach your event handlers AFTER the DOM tree is fully loaded ("DOM ready").
Careful though, older browsers might not support that event (it only became standardized with HTML5, although older Mozilla browsers will already know it)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (ev) {
        var button = document.getElementById("buttonid");
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log("alert");
        });
    }, true);
</script>
</head>
```

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G3YWJ/